# Strange pandas.DataFrame.sum(axis=1) behaviour

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame compiled from some web data (for tennis games) that exhibits strange behaviour when summing across selected rows.

```
DataFrame:
In [178]: tdf.shape
Out[178]: (47028, 57)

In [201]: cols
Out[201]: ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5']

In [177]: tdf[cols].head()
Out[177]:
L1 L2   L3  L4  L5   W1 W2   W3  W4  W5
0  4.0  2  NaN NaN NaN  6.0  6  NaN NaN NaN
1  3.0  3  NaN NaN NaN  6.0  6  NaN NaN NaN
2  7.0  5    3 NaN NaN  6.0  7    6 NaN NaN
3  1.0  4  NaN NaN NaN  6.0  6  NaN NaN NaN
4  6.0  7    4 NaN NaN  7.0  5    6 NaN NaN
```

When then trying to compute the sum over the rows using `tdf[cols].sum(axis=1)`.  From the above table, the sum for the 1st row should be 18.0, but it is reported as 10, as below:

```
In [180]: tdf[cols].sum(axis=1).head()
Out[180]:
0    10.0
1     9.0
2    13.0
3     7.0
4    13.0
dtype: float64
```

The problem seems to be caused by a specific record (row 13771), because when I exclude this row, the sum is calculated correctly:

```
In [182]: tdf.iloc[:13771][cols].sum(axis=1).head()
Out[182]:
0    18.0
1    18.0
2    34.0
3    17.0
4    35.0
dtype: float64
```

whereas, including it:

```
In [183]: tdf.iloc[:13772][cols].sum(axis=1).head()
Out[183]:
0    10.0
1     9.0
2    13.0
3     7.0
4    13.0
dtype: float64
```

Gives the wrong result for the entire column.

The offending record is as follows:

```
In [196]: tdf[cols].iloc[13771]
Out[196]:
L1      1
L2      1
L3    NaN
L4    NaN
L5    NaN
W1      6
W2      0
W3
W4    NaN
W5    NaN
Name: 13771, dtype: object

In [197]: tdf[cols].iloc[13771].W3
Out[197]: ' '

In [198]: type(tdf[cols].iloc[13771].W3)
Out[198]: str
```

I'm running the following versions:

```
In [192]: sys.version
Out[192]: '3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'
In [193]: pd.__version__
Out[193]: '0.19.2'
In [194]: np.__version__
Out[194]: '1.12.0'
```

Surely a single poorly formatted record should not influence the sum of other records? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `empty string` - then `dtype` of column `W3` is `object` (obviously `string`) and `sum` omit it.

Solutions:

Try replace problematic `empty string` value to `NaN` and then cast to `float`

```
tdf.loc[13771, 'W3'] = np.nan

tdf.W3 = tdf.W3.astype(float)
```

Or try replace all empty strings to `NaN` in subset `cols`:

```
tdf[cols] = tdf[cols].replace({'':np.nan})
#if necessary
tdf[cols] = tdf[cols].astype(float)
```

Another solution is use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) in problematic column - replace all non numeric to `NaN`:

```
tdf.W3 = pd.to_numerice(tdf.W3, erors='coerce')
```

Or generally apply for columns `cols`:

```
tdf[cols] = tdf[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers & quick reply.  Applying `to_numeric` does the trick! But the fact that it silently failed on the string record does not seem desireable.  I'll go with this though.